# Numpy cast from signed to unsigned int with 'same_kind'

Tags: numpy, casting, unsigned-integer

In numpy, it looks like I can cast using `same_kind` from uint to int, but not from int to uint, which sort-of makes sense:

```
> np.array([0, 2], dtype=np.uint8).astype(np.int64, casting='same_kind')
array([0, 2])
> np.array([0, 2], dtype=np.int8).astype(np.uint64, casting='same_kind')
TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('int8') to dtype('uint64') according to the rule 'same_kind'
```

I want to cast like this, after having checked the bounds of the values in the array (so that I know I won't lose data). But if I do `casting='unsafe'` after bounds checking, I will allow casts from eg. floats (which I don't want to permit). So how can I allow int<=>uint casting but ban other types?

Comment: As a workaround you could cast to the signed type and then view cast to the unsigned: `a.astype(np.int64, casting='same_kind').view(np.uint64)`

Answer (score 2):

For the moment I'm simply hacking around this by checking `np.dtype(from_dtype).kind == 'i' and np.dtype(to_dtype).kind == 'u'` and if so, setting `casting = 'unsafe'`, but that seems a bit hacky to me!

FWIW, here is the function I'm using now:

```
def safe_np_int_conversion(int_array, dtype=np.uint8, copy=True):
    """
    A few functions require arrays of a certain type (e.g. np.int32, np.uint8).
    To allow functions to accept standard numpy integer arrays (usually of 
    dtype=np.int64) we cast but check bounds to avoid wrap-around
    conversion errors (numpy doesn't seem to provide this functionality)
    """
    int_array = np.array(int_array)
    if int_array.size == 0:
        return int_array.astype(dtype, copy=copy)  # Allow empty arrays of any type
    try:
        return int_array.astype(dtype, casting='safe', copy=copy)
    except TypeError:
        bounds = np.iinfo(dtype)
        if np.all(int_array >= bounds.min) and np.all(int_array <= bounds.max):
            if int_array.dtype.kind == 'i' and np.dtype(dtype).kind == 'u':
                # Allow casting from int to unsigned int, since we have checked bounds
                casting = 'unsafe'
            else:
                # Raise a TypeError when we try to convert from, e.g., a float.
                casting = 'same_kind'
            return int_array.astype(dtype, casting=casting, copy=copy)
        else:
            raise OverflowError("Cannot convert safely to {} type".format(dtype))
```

Comment: If you're converting ints, *and* you need casting='unsafe', *and* you have no other information about the ints, then you are going get wrong answers half the time.

Comment: Why is this? My version above does bounds checking, so I think it should be safe?

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes, your code is good here - this was a general principle that I was stating, not a critique of your code.

Answer (score 1):

`np.int8` cover signed numbers from -128 to 127, whereas, `np.uint64` covers numbers from 0 to 1.844e+19 . Which means that your numpy casting will not be able to represent the negative values from `np.int8`.

Numpy works in a way to return consistent dtypes based only on the dtypes of the arguments. This is very important to avoid

Not every signed int can be safely cast into an unsigned int even in the larger unsigned interval.

In this case, you will actually lose your data and do the opposite of what you wanted from the beginning. Here is a better way:

```
np.array([0, 2], dtype=np.int8).view(np.uint64)
```

Comment: Surely every signed int within e.g. the interval `np.iinfo(np.uint8).min` and `np.iinfo(np.uint8).max` can be safely converted to `np.uint8`, no?

Comment: I don't see how your version allows me to cast an array to unsigned ints from a signed int array containing only positive integers (within the right range)? In your example you still end up with a signed int array.

Comment: He wanted to convert from `[-128, 127]` to `[0, 18446744073709551615]` which not possible for the negative values.

Comment: You can't cast negative values to an unsigned interval, can you?

Comment: No, I want to convert e.g. `np.array([0, 2], dtype=np.int8)` to an unsigned array, but disallow `np.array([0, 2], dtype=np.float)`

Comment: You correctly say that I won't be able to cast -128 to `np.uint64` because of losing data. But numpy does in fact allow me to cast `np.array([1000])` to `np.uint8` (result = `array([232], dtype=uint8)`), even though this also loses data.

Comment: I got what you mean. I updated my answer, is that what you want ?

Comment: Sorry - not quite, although the `view` method might indeed be an alternative approach. I've posted my current solution as an answer, but it seems a bit fragile to me.

Comment: I would argue the `view` is the simplest way to go but it's all up to you. Sorry if I could not get the answer you wanted :(

Comment: I think 'view' might do weird things with different sizes, e.g. np.int32 being viewed as np.int8.